# How much to charge for a re-posting of a video?

Tags: video, editing, streaming

Created a short promotional video for a client, it's an online magazine.

For the sake of example, let's say I charged the magazine $700. The video is embedded into the magazine using a proprietary method (ie: not youtube, vimeo, or any other video sharing site with embed options). This is fine.

Now the video happens to be something of an pseudo-official biography on a local artist (hes in it, he talks in it, official interview stuff), but the video wasn't made FOR him, but now he's inquiring how much it would cost him to embed the video on HIS site as well, for marketing purposes.

Again, lets say I charged the Magazine $700 (2.5min video), how much should I charge for a re-embed?

(ps: I own the copyrights)

Comment: Good question, though I'm not sure it's appropriate for fact-based Q&A format of SE sites.  Answers are likely to all begin with "it depends".

Comment: I expect that, absolutely, it's not a "defined" scale, I just have no idea where to start, and most AV forums take 3 years for people to respond :\

Comment: @DJDarkViper As-is, this question is too vague for this site, as it's basically [discussion without any real definitive answer](http://avp.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), and it's also too localized, especially with the price discussion. You could probably re-word it though, to ask "Is there an established practice in this situation?" rather than "what should I charge him?".

Comment: @DJDarkViper I can give you a hand with it if you're not sure - @-reply me in chat if you like!

Answer (score 1):

That is completely up to you, how much is it worth to you, etc.  Keeping in mind you have to do zero additional work on it to give it to him, and if he were to put it up on his site without your knowledge you would loose nothing.

Answer (score -1):

The same amount of money for every person. But if he couldn't afford it then go for less 200? 300? ;)

Comment: my mind was also saying something in the ballpark os $200, as it's no real extra work on my part...